# Conflicting answers in an Olympiad Math problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, contest-math

**This problem was asked in Baltic Way MO 2014 and an Olympiad training camp**

***Problem***: *In how many ways can we paint 16 seats in a row, each red or green, in such a way that
the number of consecutive seats painted in the same colour is always odd?*

The official solution has an answer of $1974$ in which Fibonacci Series was used. But in the training camp, the answer was written as $2^{15}$.

I am not sure which is correct. Anyone? Please provide an explanation as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write $x_n$ for the number of ways to paint $n$ seats with the first seat red. Clearly the number of ways with the first seat green is equal, so your answer will be $2x_{16}$.

Note that $x_1=1$ and $x_2=1$ (the only possibility is RG). Now for $n>2$ we have two options. Either the second seat is green, in which case the number of possibilities is the number of ways to paint $n-1$ seats, starting with green, i.e. $x_{n-1}$, or the second and third seats are red. The number of ways to complete the latter is the same as the number of ways to paint $n-2$ seats, starting red (since the first two seats do not affect parity). Thus $x_n=x_{n-1}+x_{n-2}$, and $x_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number.

So $1974=2F_{16}$ is correct. $2^{15}$ is obviously too large anyway - that would mean if you painted the seats at random there would be a $50\%$ chance of satisfying this property!